# Where is the ArcGIS Snippet Finder?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, development

I am just going through the "Building custom UI elements using add-ins" walkthrough.  ArcGIS integrated development environment (IDE) is installed. No problems creating the ArcMap Add-on project until i get to the part where i am suppose to RIGHT-CLICK in the editor window and select the ArcGIS Snippet Finder...

There is no ArcGIS Snippet Finder on the shortcut menu that pops up (see attached)

An example of what i should be seeing is here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/a...0000036s000000

Where is the Snippet Finder?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the Desktop and Engine SDK installed on your box (is that what you mean by "ArcGIS integrated development environment (IDE) is installed")?

Comment: Yes Installed. (The ArcGIS Visual Studio IDE Integration Framework is an optional installation feature included with the ArcObjects software development kit (SDK) for .NET)  More here:http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Visual_Studio_integration/000100000m7n000000/

Comment: Is it possible to install the SDK without the Snippet Finder? If so would you recommend re-installing?

Comment: I notice you are using VS Express...could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Apparently VS Express is fully supported. Perhaps not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Saw a few posts about this on the ESRI forums.
This [one in particular](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/5627-ArcGIS-10-Pre-Release-Visual-Studio-Express-2008-Integration-Issues?p=45803#post45803) mentions:

for Visual Studio Express 2008/ArcGIS 10;
- in VS, click on Tools>Code Snippets Manager
- Click on Add... and browse to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common 7\IDE\VBExpress\Snippets\ArcObjects
- Click OK and OK
- ArcObjects will now appear in the "Insert Snippet" context menu

Does that work?

For ArcGIS10.1 with MS Visual Studio Express 2010 users, change the above path to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VCSExpress\Snippets\ArcObjects if using VC#, and presumably change VCSExpress to VBExpress if you're going down the VB route.

Comment: Thanks Simon. This seems to be the VBExpress version of the functionality although one can hardly call it a "Finder". (No my problem is finding the snippets without the search option) I have to admin my disappointment with ESRI in this regard and what they claim to be a "replacement" for VBA. VS Express is nowhere near, it seems more and more obvious to me that a full version of VS is required in order to migrate VBA to Add-Ins.

Comment: Simon, do you have any idea where I could find a 'list' of available snippets?

Comment: Found it. ArcObject->Mapping

Answer (score 3):

I run into the same problem, and Simon's suggestion above pretty much helped my situation. A couple of extra steps I did:

1. In VB Express, under tool, the option of "code snippet manager" was not visible. To access this option, I had to the settings under tool from "Basic Settings" to "Expert Settings".
2. The path that Simon outlined above, in my case, was under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VCSExpress\Snippets\ArcObjects. The only difference being C:\Program Files (x86) vs. C:\Program Files.

I followed the steps above, and was able get access to "Arcobjects" snippets within VB Express 2010.

Comment: You just prevented a very heavy head-desk! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was the case for you but, I read on the [ESRI forum](http://forums.esri.com/thread.asp?t=280441&f=1170&c=93) that for 9.3 they suggested a reinstall the SDK if VS2008 is installed after the SDK.

Comment: I installed VS Express first then ArcGIS 10